# How do I keep an object from wrapping around a floated image?

Tags: css, css-float, css-position, word-wrap

The following image shows the result of an `<img>` tag floating left.  The margins aren't all worked out, but the `<h1>` tag is wrapping.

[image]

**Question:**  The book statistics in the brown area are inside a `<table>` block.  When it wraps, it wraps as a complete block as shown in the image.  Is it possible to exclude the `<table>` block from the wrapping caused by `<img style="float:left;">`?

- I tried using both `position` and `float` together.  It didn't work.  `<clear>` applies only to the floated object, not to wrapped objects.
- Conceptually, I'm looking for the equivalent of the following fictional CSS assignment, which would be applied to the `<table>` tag: `ignore-float:true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for isn't possible, so far as I can tell, with the current order of your HTML markup. If you add another div wrapped around the image and the table, and float the div itself, the table will stay under the image and other elements will wrap around them.

```
<h1>Header</h1>
<div class="image-wrap">
  <img src="..." alt="" />
  <table> ... </table>
</div>
<p>Paragraph text</p>
```

and for your CSS:

```
.image-wrap { float: left; max-width: 200px; }
.image-wrap img { display: block; }
```

Comment: That was a brilliant idea, but rather than creating a "T" shaped object to wrap around, it's (understandably) a rectangular object that wants everything to wrap along the right-most edge.  However, it does expose a potential solution.  Back in the good old days ('89-'94) we HTML'ers used `float` with a whole bunch of transparent and thin-but-varying-width `div` blocks to create shaped (e.g., curved) float-arounds.  It's old tech, but it might be my only solution - and I wouldn't have even remembered it without this idea.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey great, well written answer. @JBH said it perfectly. Brilliant idea.